# Parsing in memory CSV files from zip archives

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-zipfile

I'm working on a new library which will allow the user to parse any file (`xlsx`, `csv`, `json`, `tar`, `zip`, `txt`) into generators.

Now I'm stuck at `zip` archive and when I try to parse a `csv` from it, I get
`io.UnsupportedOperation: seek` immediately after `elem.seek(0)`. The `csv` file is a simple one 4x4 rows and columns. If I parse the `csv` using the `csv_parser` I get what I want, but trying to parse it from a zip archive... boom. Error!

```
with open("/Users/ro/Downloads/archive_file/csv.zip", 'r') as my_file_file:
    asd = parse_zip(my_file_file)
    print asd
```

Where `parse_zip` is:

```
def parse_zip(element):
"""Function for manipulating zip files"""
try:
    my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(element, 'r')
except zipfile.BadZipfile:
    raise err.NestedArchives(element)
else:
    my_file = my_zip.open('corect_csv.csv')
    # print my_file
    my_mime = csv_tsv_parser.parse_csv_tsv(my_file)
    print list(my_mime)
```

And `parse_cvs_tsv` is:

```
def _csv_tsv_parser(element):
"""Helper function for csv and tsv files that return an generator"""

   for row in element:
       if any(s for s in row):
          yield row

def parse_csv_tsv(elem):
"""Function for manipulating all the csv files"""

   dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(elem.readline())
   elem.seek(0)

   data_file = csv.reader(elem, dialect)

   read_data = _csv_tsv_parser(data_file)

   yield '', read_data
```

Where am I wrong? Is the way I'm opening the file OK or...?

Answer (score 0):

[Zipfile.open](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) returns a *file-like* [ZipExtFile](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e176e0c105786e9f476758eb5438c57223b65e7f/Lib/zipfile.py#L524) object that inherits from [io.BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase).  `io.BufferedIOBase` does not support `seek` (only text streams in the `io` module support `seek`), hence the exception.

However, `ZipExtFile` does provide a [peek](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e176e0c105786e9f476758eb5438c57223b65e7f/Lib/zipfile.py#L628) method, which will return a number of bytes without moving the file pointer.  So changing

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(elem.readline())
elem.seek(0)
```

to

```
num_bytes = 128 # number of bytes to read
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(elem.peek(n=num_bytes))
```

solves the problem.